# How to select distinct column A, then aggregate values of of column B in DJANGO?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I try to create a crypto portfolio webpage. My problem is the following.
**Current** **Transactions** table when i render the html:

| Crypto_Name | Total Trade Value |
| --- | --- |
| BTC | 150 |
| BTC | 100 |
| DOGE | 200 |
| DOGE | 210 |

**Desired Transaction** table:

| Crypto_Name | Total Trade Value |
| --- | --- |
| BTC | 250 |
| DOGE | 410 |

I would like to **select distinct values** of Crypto_Name and t**hen summarize the values** in Total Trade Value.

*models.py*:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    """Model representing a trade."""
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey('Portfolio',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    coin = models.ForeignKey(Coin,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number_of_coins = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    trade_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.portfolio)   

    @property
    def total_trade_value(self):
        return self.trade_price * self.number_of_coins
```

*views.py query:*

```
def my_portfolio(request):
    filtered_transaction_query_by_user = Transaction.objects.filter(portfolio__user=request.user)
    ...
```

***What I have tried among many things***:

```
test = filtered_transaction_query_by_user.order_by().values('coin__name').distinct()
```

It gives me just two crypto name in an ugly format

```
{'coin__name': 'Bitcoin'}
{'coin__name': 'Doge'}
```

but the other columns are empty when I render them in the html.

I appreciate your help!!! :)

**UPDATE:** Big thank to @HudsonBarroso for the answer:

```
test = filtered_transaction_query_by_user.values('coin__name').annotate( total = (Sum(trade_price ) * Sum(number_of_coins))).order_by('-total')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
        
test = filtered_transaction_query_by_user.values('coin__name').annotate(
total = (Sum(trade_price ) * Sum(number_of_coins))).order_by('-total')
```

Comment: `.values('coin_name')` change that to `.values('coin__name')` (An extra `_` as it is a field of the related model).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer @HudsonBarroso I added an extra '' for 'total_trade_value' to work. Unfortunately, it works for each model fields, but not for the total_trade_value: Cannot resolve keyword 'total_trade_value' into field. Choices are: coin, coin_id, date, id, number_of_coins, portfolio, portfolio_id, trade_price It is a model method. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Try this one  more time:
test = filtered_transaction_query_by_user.values('coin__name').annotate(
total = (Sum(trade_price ) * Sum(number_of_coins))).order_by('-total')

Comment: That was the solution. Thank you for the help @HudsonBarroso . Big upvote!

Comment: That's nice, anytime you need @Neat1!